# View in codeigniter loading plain html tags

Tags: codeigniter

my view is just displying html tags but cannot render. it was working fine till yesterday but i dont know what is wrong here. I have tried to fix it but couldnt. checked all the httpd conf file and php ini file but still could not get anything.

[this is my login page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVHUr.png)

Comment: please check your php is enabled or not

Comment: Please check your log file for what you exact error .

Comment: how you can load the view?

Comment: $this->load->view('file name');

Comment: You haven't shown us the CI code you use to [load your view](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-a-view).  Also, what does your browser devtools show for the network request?  Check the content type.  Also, your HTML is [missing a doctype](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#html5-doctype).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load a particular view file you will use the following method

```
$this->load->view('file_name');
```